# XEV doesn't detect my key - is there any hope?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keys

On my keyboard, there are three keys - Cut, Copy, and Paste:

[image]

However, I cannot assign these as `xev` doesn't detect them. What can I do?

Comment: How are you going to assign the keys?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Not sure - can that be done with xmodmap?

Comment: Not sure, but there are alternative ways to find out the key sym etc. Are you going to use it in a script?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'd just like to be able to press it and copy / paste / cut the text.

Comment: I didn't try it yet (am on mobile) but did you see this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys

Comment: Note that the deleted answer did detect the key.

Comment: @Tim what was the answer?

Comment: @selurvedu `keytouch keytouch-editor`

Comment: @selurvedu I've re-posted the deleted answer in case it helps you

Answer (score 1):

If `xev` can't detect the keys then you will need to use or write a different driver that can enable the keys. That keyboard looks very much like a rebranded Logitech keyboard so their drivers might be a start.

Answer (score 1):

Posted by [tempforFind Me In The Woods](https://askubuntu.com/users/463933/tempforfind-me-in-the-woods) on May 1 2016. Untested, do not know if this will work 7 years later.

> You may be able to get the keyboard's unrecognized keys mapped with KeyTouch. *Note that if your keyboard is not yet supported, you can get in touch with the developer [Here](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/keytouch_editor/).*
>
> Install it with `sudo apt-get install keytouch keytouch-editor` .
>
> The app will be located in **System -> Preferences -> Keytouch**

Comment: Thanks, the program is functional, it works with all other extra buttons, but the cut-copy-paste buttons are still not detected. I think my PS/2 to USB adapter may be the culprit. It also detected my extra mouse buttons which I currently use as forward and back buttons – these are the default actions, but it's good to know I can remap them if I need to.

Comment: @selurvedu yeah, I expect those buttons are going to only be implemented for the windows drivers. Someone could probably release a new driver, but given it's a very old keyboard I doubt it will happen...